# Android navigation drawer with section

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I searched a lot in google but couldn't find something good. I want use navigation drawer like shown in the picture. Look carefully in item 4. when click on this item opens option. How could I do this?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SlidingMenu is an Open Source Android library that allows you to easily create applications with sliding menus like in the Google+.

Feel free to use it all you want in your Android apps provided that you [cite this project](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/sliding-menu/) and [Demo HERE](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/)

Another tool you can use is [Navigation Drawer](http://www.javahispano.org/android/2013/5/23/patron-de-diseo-navigation-drawer.html)